# What is an API in basics?

Tags: api

I want to know, what an API really means? And what it is meant for? Please give me a clear explanation with some examples?

Note: Basics of API for a first timer.

Thanks
Manikandan

Comment: If you hoover with your mouse over the api tag, you'll see the answer to your question: "API stands for Application Programming Interface. A program's API defines the proper way for a developer to request services from that program."

Comment: For *"What is"* questions, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is a better resource than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API is a an interface (set of methods and fields with buound by rules how to use them) of an application or library. It is a standardised way of using application programatically.

An analogy from a real world would be a house furnace. You use it every day for heating (just like you use some application, let's say music player for playing songs). But when you want to change something in your furnace, reprogram it, set temperatures for a given period, you need to use its interface (gauges, buttons, valves and so on) in a proper way (you need to know what to change and in which order). This can be loosely considered as furnace's "API".

Comment: Furnaces are not all that common in all parts of the world. A better physical world  analogy is to talk about physical connectors like power plugs network connectors etc. They are all similar standardized concepts where it does not matter what equipment is in the other end just as long as you can connect to the standard connector. The API is now a description of the standard connectors for computer applications.